# How can i write test for apex trigger using assert method?

Tags: testing, triggers, apex

How can i write test for apex trigger using assert method?

Here is my code:

```
trigger ProductTrigger on Product__c (before insert, before update) { 
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult F = Product__c.Description__c.getDescribe(); 
    Integer lengthOfField = F.getLength();
    List<Product__c> prList = new list<Product__c>(); 
    for(Product__c pr: trigger.new){
        pr.AddedDate__c=system.today();
        if (String.isNotEmpty(pr.Description__c)) {
           pr.Description__c = pr.Description__c.abbreviate(lengthOfField);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test a trigger the same way you would test a normal logic class. Just create a new test class, then create a new product in your test class, insert it, query for it, and verify that the fields you expected your trigger to change have been updated.

Calling the insert statement inside of StartTest()/StopTest() ensures that the trigger logic completes before the assertions are evaluated.

You can test the update logic in the same fashion and also test inserting & updating lists of objects.

```
@isTest
public class Test_ProductTrigger {

    @isTest
    static void test_getNewApp()
    {
        Product__c product = Product__c();
        product.yourFieldToTest = 'someValue';

        Test.startTest();
             insert products;
        Test.stopTest();

        Product__c newProduct = [SELECT yourFieldToTest FROM Product WHERE Id = product.Id LIMIT 1];

        system.assert('yourExpectedValue' == newProduct.yourFieldToTest);
        // You can also use system.assertEquals to do the same test
        system.assertEquals('yourExpectedValue', newProduct.yourFieldToTest);

    }
}
```